# Unable to access API sitting behind APIM from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-function-app

We are working on Azure.

[image]

To secure our API's we have APIM in front of it. We have App Registration based security policy on APIM to secure our API's for external world users. In the policy list we have added api1.azurewebsites.net;api2.azurewebsites.net;api3.azurewebsites.net domain entries so if api1 is calling api 2 it is allowed.

We also have a functionapp with c# .netcore code and it is calling api 3  but get 401 error.  We added functionalapp domain in the above list but still access is denied.

How to resolve this please?

Comment: Could you add more information about the policy you're using? Just strip out any sensitive information. Do your APIs in APIM require subscription key?

Comment: We have key values defined in APIM and they are basically the domain names of API's. In policy we check the hosts so when api 1 calls api 2 in request headers the domain name is set automatically and APIM checks it. But when api is called from WITHIN azure function the request does not contain any valid header and so policy rejects it. Is there a way to set header of api automatically that starts from within Azure function  and this may resolve the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to write code in your function to set header before request the api in your function code ?

Comment: I did that  to overcome this issue. However if azure function host gets added automatically may NOT be a clean way. if at least I know how azure function set the header I can handle that in policy according.